# Capture IIS 8 stats

Tags: networking, windows-8, iis

Is there any good application to look at the stats for IIS8? Like bandwidth usage, hits/day, downloads/day etc.? I used to use [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) which had these features within the file server program but HFS itself has security flaws and is not powerful enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://logit.io before to acheive this information, they can provide you with a centralised place to store all your logs and run searches a queries against your data.

This was particularly useful when we had 9 webservers and we could identify any issues pretty quickly!

Answer (score -1):

Bandwidth usage you can monitor using the Performance monitor included in Windows 8, by adding a performance counter for your network card. Counting hits and downloads should be done through javascript on the site level, not by the web server itself.

So to answer you question:

- You can monitor bandwidth
- You cant monitor hits and downloads